# Windows modify system files once reboot or shutdown button pressed

Tags: windows, file, registry, system

Is there any way to modify a system file when the reboot/shutdown button is pressed without using an external tool like a Linux live CD?

I came across a post that suggested modifying a registry value to achieve this, but unfortunately, it didn't work for me. How can I tell Windows to overwrite a system file on the next reboot?

I am solely focused on finding a solution within the current parameters and do not wish to explore alternative methods at the moment.

Edit: if you know answer here
https://superuser.com/questions/1795020/windows-modify-system-files-once-reboot-or-shutdown-button-pressed/1795290?noredirect=1#comment2811858_1795290